# Images (as base64 data) in UWP WebView (through Xamarin.Forms)?

Tags: html, image, xamarin.forms, webview, uwp

In my current app, I have multiple pages which are based on a HTML content. This content is generated by multiple files. First there is a layout template file which has a placeholder for the content. This content comes from *.resx files within my Forms project. And the last part are the images from a database or embedded resources, these are parsed into the content by self defined tags and are added as base64 formatted data strings in the img src tag.

This works really fine on iOS and Android. However, on UWP the whole HTML page stays blank as soon as there is a single img src tag filled. If I left the img src empty or filled with not existing stuff it also works fine. Is there maybe some kind of stupid character limit for the img src tag on UWP?

Comment: What does your image path look like? Does it contain some blank space or illegal characters? And where did you place your images, can they be displayed by an Image control on UWP?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT this makes no sense. 1. it’s HTML so no Image Control involved. 2. base64 Data strings as source. So no there is no path at all. It works when I display it from the www but won’t work if I set the string data directly. Maybe there is some kind of length limit on UWP because base64 Image data makes the string pretty large but then I would expect some kind of exception...

Comment: Could you please share a sample here to help me reproduce your issue?